# Can't change annotation image property once is initialized

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator

I create a map module with a custom local image and works fine but later i want to change it for other local image and the image doesnt change on Android, debugging i find the variable "anno.image" does change the value of image with the image i want but doenst render on the map. 
This is the way im using to create and change the image property.
Thanks in advice.

```
anno.image = "/Imagenes/carrito1.png";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it's not rendering the new image but you can remove and re-add this same annotation and it will behave exactly the same way. So basically you can do something like this:

```
anno = Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude : anno.latitude,
    longitude : anno.longitude,
    image : "/Imagenes/carrito1.png",
    ..... // copy other properties whatever you had on this anno
});

MapView.addAnnotations([anno]);
```